# How to use Seefood Segmenter Tensorflow Model?

Tags: tensorflow

I have had no experience in using tensorflow, so I'm not sure where to start with using a saved model. This is what I have so far in a .py file I try to run in Terminal:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

m = hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/google/seefood/segmenter/mobile_food_segmenter_V1/1')
```

After that I don't know what code to add to load an image for testing and collect the data. I've tried some things like `tf.Session()`  but nothing's really working, so it would be really helpful to get a very basic sample code that does this!

Comment: Hi @teles, Please refer to this [Tensorflow hub](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_text_classification) document to know how to use the TF hub model to train the model for different use cases. To learn about Tensorflow, this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials) will be useful.